# Angular google maps how to highlight polygon on mouse-over in uploaded KML Layer on google map:

Tags: angular5, angular-google-maps

I have uploaded KML layer into the AGM (Angular Google Maps API). It has postcode bounderies. It is showing perfectly.

Now I want to highlight perticular polygon on mouseover so that user can distiguiese the diffrence on which polygon the pointer is right now.

I am using Angular 5.2.9 and "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.3"

Bellow is the code snippet.

```
<agm-map [latitude]="boundsLat" [longitude]="boundsLon" [zoom]="5" (mapClick)="placeMarker($event)"  >                        
                <agm-marker [latitude]="r.Latitude" [longitude]="r.Longitude" *ngFor="let r of embargoViewModelListEnable; " [iconUrl]="location.icon"> 
                <agm-info-window>Latitude : {{r.Latitude}}, Longitude : {{r.Longitude}} PostCode :{{r.PostCode}}</agm-info-window></agm-marker>
                <agm-marker [latitude]="p.Latitude" [longitude]="p.Longitude" *ngFor="let p of embargoViewModelListDisable; "  [iconUrl]="location1.icon">
                <agm-info-window>Latitude : {{p.Latitude}}, Longitude : {{p.Longitude}} PostCode :{{p.PostCode}}</agm-info-window></agm-marker> 
                <agm-kml-layer [url]="'https://www.dropbox.com/s/b4vxn099oxmwxy2/PO_0800_More.kml?dl=1'"> </agm-kml-layer>                   
            </agm-map>
```